# WordPress: Category (and other Taxonomy) Meta Box in Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, meta-boxes

I've created a custom post typ and now I would like to display meta boxes with checkboxes for all possible taxonomies like the category meta box in normal posts.

Is there a way to easily display some sort of default meta box for all possible taxonomies installed in the system? Or do I have to create each meta box by myself?

Comment: When you create a taxonomy and link it to some CPT, its widget like category metabox is already displayed in the sidebar of that CPT post edit screen... if you are seeing tags like widget , and you want to use category/checkbox like, you hve two choices, either make taxonomy as Hierarchal or use callback for metabox display..

Comment: To clarify, when you ask _"Or do I have to create each meta box by myself?"_ are you wanting to have a single "Categories" meta box, a single "Tags" meta box, a single "Custom Tax 1" meta box, etc. Or are you wanting **one** meta box and the options would be the taxonomy names (like a checkbox for "Category", a checkbox for "Tag", a checkbox for "Custom Tax 1")?

Comment: I created a custom post type. I now want meta boxes for all in WordPress installed taxonomies. I don't mind having one meta box for each taxonomy. I want to use the taxonomy meta boxes so I later can query my custom post type when I'm on the archive page of one of the taxonomies.

Comment: Found it: register_taxonomy_for_object_type

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do what I want. After I call `register_post_type()` for my custom post type, I call the following code to retrieve a list of all installed public taxonomies and then add them to my post type:

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
);
$output = 'objects';
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output );
foreach  ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy )
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy->name, 'my_post_type' );
}
```